# Keep NSTableCellView in focus

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` containing `NSTableCellViews`. When the user selects the row it uses the default selection color like so:
[image]

But when the user starts editing in a `NSTextView`, the `NSTableCellView` loses it focus and goes the default grey color like so:
[image]

Is it possible for my `NSTableView` to keep it blue selection color whilst the user edits in the `NSTextView`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the text view in a different window than the table view? The gray color is for a selection in a non-key window.

Comment: No the text view is in the same window as the NSTableView @KenThomases

Comment: My mistake. The gray color happens whenever the table view is not the first responder and does not contain the first responder.

Comment: @KenThomases Ok so can I override that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom subclass of `NSTableRowView` which always keeps its `emphasized` property true. You would override the getter method `-isEmphasized` to return true. While you're at it, might as well override the setter method `-setEmphasized:` to not call through to super.

If you're designing in IB, you can add a custom view to one of the table columns. In the Identity inspector set its class to your custom subview of `NSTableRowView`. Also, set its identifier to "NSTableViewRowViewKey". That's a special identifier that causes the table view to use it as its row view.

If you want to do this in code, you can implement the table view delegate method `-tableView:rowViewForRow:` to return an instance of your custom row view class. Follow the docs for that method and call `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` on the table view, first, to try to get a row view from the table's reuse queue. Pass any identifier you like. If the table view returns `nil`, create an instance of your class and set its `identifier` property to the same value you're using to look it up.

Be warned, though, that changing the meaning of the highlight color like this is likely to confuse your users. For example, they may glance at your UI, see that the table looks like it has focus, and try to use the arrow keys to move the selected row around. They'll be surprised to discover they've moved the insertion point around in the text view.